# How can I mix the output of 2 LUTs on a video in GPUImage without going through a sequence?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I've been trying to work out whether GPUImage has an out of the box solution for what I'm trying to do.

I have 2 LUTs and a Video file. At the moment, I'm able to successfully play a video file and filter it through both LUTs using a combination of GPUImageView, GPUImageMovie, GPUImagePicture and GPUImageLookupFilter.

This is what I'm doing at the moment to achieve this and it works well:

```
    lutPicture1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:lutImage1];
    lutPicture2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:lutImage2];

    lutFilter1 = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
    lutFilter2 = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];

    playerItem =  [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:fileURL];
    player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    GPUImageMovie *gpuImageMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    [gpuImageMovie addTarget: lutFilter1];
    [lutPicture1 addTarget: lutFilter1];
    [lutPicture1 processImage];
    [lutFilter1 addTarget: lutFilter2];

    [lutPicture2 addTarget: lutFilter2];
    [lutPicture2 processImage];
    [lutFilter2 addTarget: gpuImageView];

    [gpuImageMovie startProcessing];
    [player play];
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but the output will be the result of first passing it through my filter named "lutFilter1", THEN passing the output of that through "lutFilter2".

However, I don't want to execute the filters in a sequence like this.

I don't know if it's possible, but I would like to be able to do the following:

1. given a "position" in my Video
2. get the corresponding colour for it from "lutImage1"
3. get the corresponding colour for it from "lutImage2"
4. mix the colours returned from "lutImage1" and "lutImage2"
5. return the mixed colour as the output.

I've seen a filter in the framework called GPUImageSoftEleganceFilter which looks like it might do something similar using two LUTs, but being relatively new to this stuff I'd like it if someone can help me out and tell me if what I'm trying to do is achievable using GPUImage, and if so perhaps point me in the right direction :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out the class to handle what I'm trying to do in **GPUImage** is **GPUImageThreeInputFilter**.

I ended up creating a sub class of **GPUImageThreeInputFilter** and adding my custom vertex and fragment shaders within my subclass.

If you're interested to do the same, here is a basic vertex shader setup to get your started:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate2;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate3;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate2;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate3;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
    textureCoordinate2 = inputTextureCoordinate2.xy;
    textureCoordinate3 = inputTextureCoordinate3.xy;
}
```

And a basic fragment shader to go along with this. NOTE: The fragment shader below is not using the image texture rendered at location 3, but it would be straightforward to modify this should you wish. Also note "intensity" needs to be set, you can hard code to a float e.g. 1.0 for demonstrative purposes.

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2;
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate3;

uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture3;

uniform lowp float intensity;

void main()
{
    highp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

    highp float blueColor = textureColor.b * 63.0;

    highp vec2 quad1;
    quad1.y = floor(floor(blueColor) / 8.0);
    quad1.x = floor(blueColor) - (quad1.y * 8.0);

    highp vec2 quad2;
    quad2.y = floor(ceil(blueColor) / 8.0);
    quad2.x = ceil(blueColor) - (quad2.y * 8.0);

    highp vec2 texPos1;
    texPos1.x = (quad1.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
    texPos1.y = (quad1.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);

    highp vec2 texPos2;
    texPos2.x = (quad2.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
    texPos2.y = (quad2.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);

    lowp vec4 newColor1 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos1);
    lowp vec4 newColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos2);

    lowp vec4 newColor = mix(newColor1, newColor2, fract(blueColor));
    gl_FragColor = mix(textureColor, vec4(newColor.rgb, textureColor.w), intensity);
}
```

And my Objective-C setup to hook this all up is as follows:

```
// The URL of the video file in our Bundle we want to play
NSURL *videoFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: videoFilePath];

playerItem =  [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL: videoFileURL];
player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem: playerItem];

// GPUCustomThreeInputFilter inherits from GPUImageThreeInputFilter
customThreeInputFilter = [[GPUCustomThreeInputFilter alloc] init];

GPUImageMovie *gpuImageMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[gpuImageMovie addTarget: customThreeInputFilter atTextureLocation:0];

// This texture will be available at "inputImageTexture2" in our fragment shader
[gpuImagePicture1 addTarget: customThreeInputFilter atTextureLocation:1];
[gpuImagePicture1 processImage];

// This texture will be available at "inputImageTexture3" in our fragment shader
[gpuImagePicture2 addTarget: customThreeInputFilter atTextureLocation:2];
[gpuImagePicture2 processImage];

// gpuImageView is an instance of GPUImageView and is added to our ViewController in the normal way via [self.view addSubview: gpuImageView]
[customThreeInputFilter addTarget: gpuImageView];

[gpuImageMovie startProcessing];
[player play];
```

I hope this helps anyone trying to do the same thing.